# How to mute document sound by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am using an advertising code that play a movie in `<iframe>` each  3 Minutes

This sound annoying user, How could i mute it,

I could not change in `<iframe>` body because of `CROSS-ORIGIN`

Have it a solution?

**Selection source:**

```
<div data-asm-done="1" class="asm_async_creative" data-asm-host="xxlmarketingsolution.adspirit.de" data-asm-params="pid=1" id="asmvi1" style="position:relative; width:610px; height:343px;">
<script src="//xxlmarketingsolution.adspirit.de/adscript.php?async=asmvi1&amp;wpcn=asm29334x1466076618999&amp;ref=http%3A%2F%2Ftv.spielenxxl.de%2F&amp;swf=21&amp;scx=1920&amp;scy=1080&amp;vis=4&amp;tz=1466076619000&amp;pid=1"></script><ins id="asm_fls36x7558266y1466076621" style="display: inline-block; width: 610px; height: 343px; text-align: left;" class=""><span id="asmspan_vastwrapper5192281" style="font-size: 1px; width: 1px; height: 1px; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block;" class="asm_flash"><object data="http://cdn.adspirit.de/banner/advastwrapper.swf" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="https://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=21,0,0,0" id="adspiritflashvastwrapper5192281" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="1" width="1"> <param name="movie" value="http://cdn.adspirit.de/banner/advastwrapper.swf"> <param name="flashvars" value="path=http%3A%2F%2Fvideo-adserver.ibillboard.com%2FgetAd%3Ftagid%3Dee7891f6-4cc8-4155-d266-c2a0df3f0d65&amp;id=adspiritflashvastwrapper5192281&amp;player_id=adspiritflashvastwrapper5192281">  <param name="quality" value="autohigh">  <param name="transparency" value="yes">  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">  <param name="allowNetworking" value="all">  <param name="wmode" value="transparent">  <param name="swLiveConnect" value="true">  <embed src="http://cdn.adspirit.de/banner/advastwrapper.swf" flashvars="path=http%3A%2F%2Fvideo-adserver.ibillboard.com%2FgetAd%3Ftagid%3Dee7891f6-4cc8-4155-d266-c2a0df3f0d65&amp;id=adspiritflashvastwrapper5192281&amp;player_id=adspiritflashvastwrapper5192281" allownetworking="all" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" name="adspiritflashvastwrapper5192281" transperency="yes" swliveconnect="true" quality="autohigh" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="https://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" wmode="transparent" menu="false" height="1" width="1"> </object></span><span id="asmspan_5192281_vpaid" style="font-size: 1px; width: 1px; height: 1px; overflow: hidden; display: none;" class="asm_flash"><object data="http://cdn.adspirit.de/banner/advpaid.swf" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="https://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=21,0,0,0" id="adspiritflash5192281_vpaid" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="343" width="610"> <param name="movie" value="http://cdn.adspirit.de/banner/advpaid.swf"> <param name="flashvars" value="wmode=opaque&amp;id=adspiritflash5192281_vpaid&amp;player_id=adspiritflash5192281_vpaid">  <param name="quality" value="autohigh">  <param name="transparency" value="yes">  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">  <param name="allowNetworking" value="all">  <param name="wmode" value="opaque">  <param name="swLiveConnect" value="true">  <embed src="http://cdn.adspirit.de/banner/advpaid.swf" flashvars="wmode=opaque&amp;id=adspiritflash5192281_vpaid&amp;player_id=adspiritflash5192281_vpaid" allownetworking="all" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" name="adspiritflash5192281_vpaid" transperency="yes" swliveconnect="true" quality="autohigh" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="https://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" wmode="opaque" menu="false" height="343" width="610"> </object></span><script src="http://cdn.adspirit.de/banner/vastwrapper_async.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="http://cdn.adspirit.de/banner/vast_async.js" type="text/javascript"></script></ins><span id="asmspan_5192281" style="font-size: 1px; overflow: hidden; width: 610px; height: 343px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 991919991; display: inline-block;" class="asm_flash"><object data="http://cdn.adspirit.de/banner/admovie.swf" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="https://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=21,0,0,0" id="adspiritflash5192281" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="343" width="610"> <param name="movie" value="http://cdn.adspirit.de/banner/admovie.swf"> <param name="flashvars" value="&amp;movie=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn.adspirit.de%2Fbanner%2F1x1.flv&amp;clickurl=http%3A%2F%2Fxxlmarketingsolution.adspirit.de%2Fadclick.php%3Ftz%3D1466076621131449%3Bpid%3D1%3Bkid%3D30%3Bwmid%3D36%3Bwsid%3D4%3Buid%3D1%3Bord%3D1466076621&amp;&amp;fgcolor=0xFFFFFF&amp;bgcolor=0xFFFFFF&amp;txcolor=0xFFFFFF&amp;volume=25&amp;&amp;MouseMovePlay=off&amp;autoload=on&amp;mute=off&amp;MouseMoveSound=off&amp;FLVmenu=off&amp;autorewind=off&amp;loop=off&amp;muteonly=off&amp;MuteButton=on&amp;FLVzoom=on&amp;FullscreenButton=off&amp;runtime=off&amp;MouseOutMute=off&amp;replay=off&amp;volumebar=on&amp;PlayButton=off&amp;clicktarget=_blank&amp;clickJSFunction=window.plyr_5192281_click&amp;stopJSFunction=window.plyr_5192281_stop&amp;playJSFunction=window.plyr_5192281_play&amp;timeJSFunction=window.plyr_5192281_time&amp;pauseJSFunction=window.plyr_5192281_pause&amp;errorJSFunction=window.plyr_5192281_error&amp;rewindJSFunction=window.plyr_5192281_rewind&amp;expandJSFunction=window.plyr_5192281_expand&amp;collapseJSFunction=window.plyr_5192281_collapse&amp;finishJSFunction=window.plyr_5192281_finish&amp;volumeChangeJSFunction=window.plyr_5192281_volume&amp;liveConnectName=adspiritflash5192281&amp;positionJSFunction=window.plyr_5192281_getPos&amp;&amp;id=adspiritflash5192281&amp;player_id=adspiritflash5192281">  <param name="quality" value="autohigh">  <param name="transparency" value="yes">  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">  <param name="allowNetworking" value="all">  <param name="wmode" value="transparent">  <param name="swLiveConnect" value="true">  <embed src="http://cdn.adspirit.de/banner/admovie.swf" flashvars="&amp;movie=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn.adspirit.de%2Fbanner%2F1x1.flv&amp;clickurl=http%3A%2F%2Fxxlmarketingsolution.adspirit.de%2Fadclick.php%3Ftz%3D1466076621131449%3Bpid%3D1%3Bkid%3D30%3Bwmid%3D36%3Bwsid%3D4%3Buid%3D1%3Bord%3D1466076621&amp;&amp;fgcolor=0xFFFFFF&amp;bgcolor=0xFFFFFF&amp;txcolor=0xFFFFFF&amp;volume=25&amp;&amp;MouseMovePlay=off&amp;autoload=on&amp;mute=off&amp;MouseMoveSound=off&amp;FLVmenu=off&amp;autorewind=off&amp;loop=off&amp;muteonly=off&amp;MuteButton=on&amp;FLVzoom=on&amp;FullscreenButton=off&amp;runtime=off&amp;MouseOutMute=off&amp;replay=off&amp;volumebar=on&amp;PlayButton=off&amp;clicktarget=_blank&amp;clickJSFunction=window.plyr_5192281_click&amp;stopJSFunction=window.plyr_5192281_stop&amp;playJSFunction=window.plyr_5192281_play&amp;timeJSFunction=window.plyr_5192281_time&amp;pauseJSFunction=window.plyr_5192281_pause&amp;errorJSFunction=window.plyr_5192281_error&amp;rewindJSFunction=window.plyr_5192281_rewind&amp;expandJSFunction=window.plyr_5192281_expand&amp;collapseJSFunction=window.plyr_5192281_collapse&amp;finishJSFunction=window.plyr_5192281_finish&amp;volumeChangeJSFunction=window.plyr_5192281_volume&amp;liveConnectName=adspiritflash5192281&amp;positionJSFunction=window.plyr_5192281_getPos&amp;&amp;id=adspiritflash5192281&amp;player_id=adspiritflash5192281" allownetworking="all" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" name="adspiritflash5192281" transperency="yes" swliveconnect="true" quality="autohigh" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="https://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" wmode="transparent" menu="false" height="343" width="610"> </object></span><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 610px; height: 343px; z-index: 999189188; display: none;" id="asmspan_5192281_asmx"><a href="#" onclick="window.asmvi1_vast.showAd(true,true); return false"><img alt="" src="" border="0" height="343" width="610"></a></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 999189188; display: none; padding: 5px 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid white; border-right: 1px solid white; background-color: rgb(202, 221, 236);" id="asmspan_5192281_skipper"><a style="font-size:11pt; color:black; font-family:Arial; line-height:1em; text-decoration:none;" href="#" onclick="window.asmvi1_vast.skipAd(); return false">Skip »</a></div></div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

<!--

var asmvi_id = "asmvi1";

var vastparam = new Object();

vastparam.width = 610;

vastparam.height = 343;

vastparam.left = 0;

vastparam.top = 0;

vastparam.events = new Object();

vastparam.events.AdLoaded = "";

vastparam.events.AdStarted = "";

vastparam.events.AdStopped = "";

vastparam.events.AdExpandedChange = "";

vastparam.events.AdRemainingTimeChange = "";

vastparam.events.AdVolumeChange = "";

vastparam.events.AdImpression = "";

vastparam.events.AdVideoStart = "";

vastparam.events.AdVideoFirstQuartile = "";

vastparam.events.AdVideoMidpoint = "";

vastparam.events.AdVideoThirdQuartile = "";

vastparam.events.AdVideoComplete = "ausblenden_ext";

vastparam.events.AdClickThru = "";

vastparam.events.AdPaused = "";

vastparam.events.AdPlaying = "";

-->

</script>

<script src="http://xxlmarketingsolution.adspirit.de/adasync.js" async="" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
/* Ausblenden des Werbeframes */
function ausblenden_ext()
    {
    document.domain = 'spielenxxl.de'; 
    window.parent.document.getElementById("werbevideo").style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>

<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-41585143-17', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

What i have tried:

```
<script>
var myini = setInterval(function(){
var embeds = document.getElementsByTagName('embed');
if(embeds){
for (var i = 0; i < embeds.length; i++) {
        embeds[i].setAttribute("flashvars", embeds[i].getAttribute("flashvars").replace("mute=off", "mute=on").replace("volume=25", "volume=0"));
        embeds[i].setAttribute("src", embeds[i].getAttribute("src"));
}
clearInterval(myini);
}
//.replace("mute=off", "mute=on").replace("volume=25", "volume=0");
}, 200);
</script>
```

Comment: Your question title sounds something else, please revise it if you can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The player is on another website and you have no control over it. The same origin policy prevents access to it via JavaScript.

If you think the advertising is unsuitable for your website, then you can either negotiate with the advertiser (or the advertising platform you are using as a middleman) or simply refuse to include it.

You can't edit the advert yourself.